# Make JSON.parse work for array of objects with quotation mark

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I am trying to store an array of object as string and restore it later. However, some elements in the objects are string and they may have ' or ". This causes an issue when I try to convert back and forth this array of objects to string with JSON.parse. Is there an standard way to resolve this issue?

```
 vars = [{'date': '04-29', 'x': 'this "x" ', 'y': '<p><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AADEQA/ANmAA9KdX/txX0/2Q=="></p>'}]
```

Comment: "_Is there an standard way to resolve this issue?_" - Yes, make sure it is serialized into valid JSON at the source.

Comment: `JSON.stringify(vars)` [don't reinvent the wheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) (and don't try to hand write valid JSON).

Comment: `const serialized = JSON.stringify(vars)` will serialize this to valid JSON that you can deserialize with `JSON.parse(serialized)`. Nothing special about this case. That's how you always work with JSON in JavaScript.

Comment: @Ivar that's not a great duplicate since it is dealing with an invalid string to start with.

Comment: Thank you all, I would try JSON.stringify and get back.

Comment: @Ivar no, this is different since I am starting from an array of objects not string.

Comment: @pilchard That applies to both questions, no? The simple replace method wont work because this question also has double quotes in it, but the `eval()` option seems to work. Haven't tried the JSON5 option.

Comment: @Roy Then you lost me. It makes little sense to use `JSON.parse()` on something that isn't a JSON/string.

Comment: No, we can use JSON.parse() on array of objects easily (given there is no problem with " and ')

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
vars=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vars));
```

result

```
[{"date":"04-29","x":"this \"x\" ","y":"<p><img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AADEQA/ANmAA9KdX/txX0/2Q==\"></p>"}]
```

or this ( I don't know what you want to reach)

```
vars = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vars).replaceAll("\\\"","'"));
```

result

```
[{"date":"04-29","x":"this 'x' ","y":"<p><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AADEQA/ANmAA9KdX/txX0/2Q=='></p>"}]
```